# Is it possible to block local mouse and keyboard input when using Teamviewr?

Tags: input, local, teamviewer

I'm using Teamviewer every day to help a distant relative with their computer problems. I need to be able to prevent MY OWN mouse input from interfering with Teamviewer when I accidentally mouse over or type on the Teamviewer window, but so far I have not been able to find out if it was possible to block my local input.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

If not, are there any utilities that could help achieve this or any alternative to Teamviewer that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RealVNC does have that option, though it's not nearly as feature-full.

You can configure the RealVNC *viewer* to disable sending keyboard and mouse input by going to Options > Inputs and unchecking "Accept Point Events" / "Accept Keyboard Events".

Alternatively, you can disable receiving inputs on the *server* by doing the same thing in the server options ( options > Inputs and uncheck "Accept Point Events" / "Accept Keyboard Events")

Comment: Please add some more information, how would you configure it, where can you get it, etc.

Comment: If you google "real vnc", it will show you http://www.realvnc.com/

From there, you can download it. The main difference between Real VNC and Teamviewer is that Real VNC does not automatically connect you if you don't already know the IP address of the server. You may have to set up port forwarding on your router, etc. These are all things you can google.